# Select element by id name ending on OpenLayers

Tags: jquery, openlayers, getelementbyid

I am trying to select an element from the ID on OpenLayers map. I have checked that the element ID is "**OpenLares_Map_4_Openlayers_Container**" but the number sometimes changes (4 to 8 or to 10). So I was trying to select the element with jQuery with the selector that finds element with the ends ([see this link](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)).

But this doesn't seem to work. And example can be seen in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iblasi/t361621b/) with the following JavaScript code:

```
// OSM
var osmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM Map");

// Map
var map = new OpenLayers.Map('mapDiv', {
    layers: [osmLayer],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
    zoom: 0
});

// All elements
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
    console.log('document.Elements: ' + i + ' -> ' + all[i].id)
}

// Select elements
var mapContainer = document.getElementById("OpenLayers_Map_4_OpenLayers_Container");
$("#tag1").text("    ->     "+mapContainer);
console.log('mapContainer: ' + mapContainer);

var id_OL_Container = $("div[id$='_OpenLayers_Container']");    // http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/
$("#tag2").text("    ->     "+id_OL_Container);
console.log('id_OL_Container: ' + id_OL_Container);
```

Does someone know what it's wrong with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important lesson: read the API documentation before diving too deep hacking. Your whole parsing logic can be replaced with:

```
console.log('id_OL_Container: ' + map.layerContainerDiv.id);
```

Here's a working JSFiddle that [demonstrates it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/kryger/5dwyo8zo/1/)

---

Another important question is *why* you think you need the ID of the element. By not depending on the element ID names you'd make your code much more clean and reliable. Your OpenLayers code should not be mixed with the DOM level code to allow independently evolving both.

Comment: why? Because I saw it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/benismobile/Lmw25/45/). Although of course, your answer is better. I didn't find that in the OL API...

Comment: I didn't ask *why* you're doing it in this particular way, but *why you think you need to do this in the first place*. You never mention what your ultimate aim is.

Comment: I just wanted to make something similar to the example I refer to

Comment: Hey, @kryger, I have a vector layer which I want to show using openlayers. I have taken the reference of  
 
 https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html   ,but my vector layers have too many fields/columns, which I do not want to show, and just want to show few desired columns, is there any way possible at https://i.stack.imgur.com/L51ms.png